# mongoose unhandled error en promesa

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, promesas

Hola buenas querria saber como hacer para que una vez terminada el update de la duracion ahi sea cuando me muestre la duracion actualizada

```js
Recipe.insertMany(recipes)
  .then(recipes => {
    console.log(`${recipes.length} inserted`);

    Recipe.findOneAndUpdate({ title: "Rigatoni alla Genovese" },{ duration: 310})
      .then(updated => next(updated))
      .then(updated => {
        console.log(updated);
      });
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log("Error updating db", err);
  });
```

Comment: Donde lo estas ejecutando? Dentro de un middleware?

Comment: Disculpa, edite mi pregunta, no estoy seguro como me puede devolver el valor actualizado

Comment: puede que sea la version de mongoose en la que estas trabajando , intenta actualizarla

Comment: pero mi pregunta es como usar el next

Comment: tu pregunta dice error en promesa, cambiala y agrega la version se mongoose mongodb y node, creo que quitando el next ya te funcionaria y te daria los resultados que tu quieres

Comment: creo que estas confundido estas utilizando el next que es de un parametro del midleware de express y tampoco estas retornando la promesa para que catch capture el error